# Crack open a Belgian lightswitch

Tags: switch, light

there!
I'm trying to open this lightswitch, I tried to put a screwdriver beneath the plastic outer frame and lift it, without success. There's a small notch below the switch itself, but I don't believe that's the way to open it.
I'm clueless on how to open and I don't know the maker. The logo on the switch looks like a little bit the pi greek letter.
Could anybody help me on that?
Thanks
(20 cent euro coin over the switch for scale[image])

Comment: the picture is unacceptably blurry

Comment: They're not worth fixing. Ten of those coins will get you a new unit. Fifty, a more exotic one.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica it's a good idea! But I need to remove it in order to change. How can I do it?